# 辞書に基づいて多重リストの置換をしたい

Tags: python

Python初心者です。よろしければご回答お願いします。
■前提条件
`dict = {0:'a',1:'b'}`
`list = [['a'], ['a', 'a', 'b']]`

■やりたいこと=>辞書dictに基づいて多重リストlistの置換をしたい
`list_henkan = [[0], [0, 0, 1]]`
2重ループを使えばなんとか置換できますが、案の定遅いので何か良い方法があれば教えてください。

Comment: 参考までに試した2重ループのコードも見せて頂けませんか。

Comment: d = {"a":0, "b":1}を逆に置いて、リスト内包表記を使えば`list_henkan = [[d[item] for item in _lst] for _lst in lst]`のように出来ます。

Comment: `dict` と `list` という変数名は python の識別子と被るので、`dic` や `lst` という名前に変更しておいた方が無難ではないでしょうか。そして、一旦、辞書の key/value を逆転してみてはどうでしょう。`swap = dict([(v, k) for (k, v) in dic.iteritems()])` その上で `[[swap[y] for y in x] for x in lst]` など。

Comment: `dic_r = {v:k for k, v in dic.items()}`
`for i in range(len(lst)):`
`for j in range(len(lst[i])):`
`lst[i][j] = dic_r[lst[i][j]]`
ありがとうございます！試した2重ループはこちらです。リスト内包表記が一番ですね：）

Comment: 本番用の自前データで速度を試してみたところ(len=735465)でどちらも10μsでした。for文は遅いと思ってましたが、この程度ですとそれほど変わらないのですね。大変勉強になりましたありがとうございました。